# What was the reason for removing raw_input() in python 3.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x, theory, python-2.x

Why has it now been merged with `input()`, and what were the advantages of using it in the first place?

Comment: It's the opposite, they removed the functionality of `input`.

Comment: Actually is the input() function that has been removed, and the Python 3.x input() is the old raw_input() function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The old `raw_input` is now called `input`. It's still the default way of reading user input.

The old `input`, on the other hand, used to `eval` whatever the user entered. `eval`, however, is dangerous (what happens if I input `import os; os.system("something evil")`?) and so this option was removed.

Originally, as we can see from [PEP 3111](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3111/), it was intended to remove both, but they chose to keep the functionality of `raw_input` around, because it was really handy.

The idea that old `input` is harmful is also indicated on the [mailing lists](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/2006-September/003583.html), when the changes were discussed:

> Personally, I think `input()` should never have existed and must go
>   no matter what. I think `raw_input()` is worth discussing -- I wouldn't
>   need it, but it's little more than a convenience function.

If you *really* need old `input`, use `eval(input(...))`.

Answer (score 2):

You almost never need the functionality of what python2 `input` provides, yet beginners constantly used it, creating error messages or hidden bugs in their application.

See [PEP 3111](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3111/).